# Subscript not working at the end of an answer

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

When formatting answers on SFF I generally include quotes for evidence to my answers, these are formatted like so.

```
> quote text<space><space>
><sub>source</sub>
```

An example of this working is [this answer of mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175787/58193). However, in two answers of mine, [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/178791/58193) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179255/58193) the last subscripted source has not subscripted and is still in the big font.

[image: Example of bug]

I have reproduced this on Windows 10, Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) and IE 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup is broken near the beginning of your [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178784/do-the-nights-watchs-maesters-have-conflicting-oaths/178791#178791):

> A toothless smile quivered ...  fleshless neck.
>   `<sub>A Game of Thrones, Jon VIII<//sub>`

The double slash (`//`) makes that the element isn't closed properly. When I fix that, your last sub tag works as intended.

I assume a similar problem for the other answer but by copy/pasting parts of the answer until it breaks in the preview is the best way to find where the markup went wrong. I assume you can find where it went wrong following that approach.

Comment: Well spotted I hadn't added a closing `</sub>` on the other example too.